# Disabling inputFields via checkBox with Zend_Dojo_Form

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

I am expanding forms that are created with `Zend_Dojo`, for this i have a special task that i have hard time solving.

The form is for purchase and consist of two address groups: `payerAddressGroup` and `deliveryAddressGroup`.

These two groups are separated, so you can define two individual addresses. Although it occurs many times that the `payerAddress` is identical to the `deliveryAddress`.

So i wanted to resolve this task by adding a checkBox that could disable the `deliveryAddressGroup`, and by the value of the checkBox only use the `payerAddress`.

The form creation is made with extension of `Zend_Dojo_Form`.

I hope it makes sense!

Thanks.

I hope it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the 'checked' property.

```
dojo.ready(function() {
    dijit.byId('shipAsPayCheckBox').watch('checked', function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
        dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(dojo.byId('fieldset-deliveryGroup')), function(w) {
            w.set('disabled', oldValue);
        });
    });
});
```

Your markup should look something like this.

```
<input id="shipAsPayCheckBox" name="shipAsPayCheckBox" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" value="1" type="checkbox" /> 
<fieldset id="fieldset-deliveryGroup">
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">Button</button>
    <label for="income1">
    U.S. Dollars
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="income1" id="income1" value="54775.53" dojoType="dijit.form.CurrencyTextBox" required="true" constraints="{fractional:true}" currency="USD" invalidMessage="Invalid amount.  Cents are required.">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i cannot exactly succeed implementing it into my existing project.

`<input id="shipAsPayCheckBox" name="shipAsPayCheckBox" value="1" type="checkbox" />` is my checkbox, and the group: `<fieldset id="fieldset-deliveryGroup">`. Is it even possible to disable an entire fieldset (group)?

Comment: thanks alot for the correction, it looks right in my eyes, but i cannot get it running for some reason. I even tried to replace `ready`with `addOnLoad`, but no luck!

Comment: `dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dijit.byId('shipAsPayCheckBox').watch('checked', function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
        dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(dojo.byId('fieldset-deliveryGroup'), function(w) {
            w.set('disabled', newValue)
        });
    });
}`

Comment: Sorry, I had some syntax errors in my original code. Fixed now with sample markup added to answer.

Comment: works now, although theres something wrong. I have set the checkbox to be "checked" from the beginning, this should disable the input fields. Although thats not the case. When i uncheck the checkbox they get disabled. Am i inserting the JS in a wrong order?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5063/discussion-between-javacake-and-flammon)